# Troubles with encoding when getting non-english characters from database in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, encoding, character-encoding

In node js I have very simple code for making requests to database:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: "databasename"
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM main_categories', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(results);
});

connection.end();
```

I'm creating database and table with this sql script:

```
CREATE DATABASE databasename
  CHARACTER SET utf8
  COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE main_categories (
  id   INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

When I'm trying to select code just in mysql console everything is looks good, but when I'm trying to get results in node.js, in console logs I see it something like this:

```
[ RowDataPacket { id: 1, name: 'Ð’Ñ–Ð·Ð¾Ñ‡ÐºÐ¸' },
  RowDataPacket { id: 2, name: 'Ð”Ð¸Ñ‚ÑÑ‡Ð¸Ð¹ Ñ‚Ñ€Ð°Ð½ÑÐ¿Ð¾Ñ€Ñ‚' },
  RowDataPacket { id: 3, name: 'ÐÐ²Ñ‚Ð¾ÐºÑ€Ñ–ÑÐ»Ð°' },
  RowDataPacket { id: 4, name: 'Ð†Ð³Ñ€Ð°ÑˆÐºÐ¸' },
  RowDataPacket { id: 5, name: 'Ð”Ð¸Ñ‚ÑÑ‡Ð° ÐºÑ–Ð¼Ð½Ð°Ñ‚Ð°' },
  RowDataPacket { id: 6, name: 'Ð’ÑÐµ Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð³Ð¾Ð´ÑƒÐ²Ð°Ð½Ð½Ñ' },
  RowDataPacket { id: 7, name: 'ÐÐºÑÐµÑÑƒÐ°Ñ€Ð¸ Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð¼Ð°Ð¼' },
  RowDataPacket { id: 8, name: 'Ð“Ñ–Ð³Ñ–Ñ”Ð½Ð° Ñ‚Ð° Ð´Ð¾Ð³Ð»ÑÐ´' } ]
```

I've tried to add `charset` in config object when using `mysql.createConnection` and any other solutions but no results unfortunately.

UPD: It might be helpful to see database variables:

```
mysql> SHOW variables WHERE variable_name LIKE '%coll%' OR variable_name LIKE '%char%';
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                     |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                      |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                      |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                      |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                    |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                      |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-5.7.19-macos10.12-x86_64/share/charsets/ |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci                                           |
| collation_database       | utf8_general_ci                                           |
| collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci                                         |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added `SET NAMES utf8;` before creating the table so it looks like this:

```
SET NAMES utf8;

CREATE TABLE main_categories (
  id   INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And that's it!

Comment: @MojtabaPourmirzaei Because it's solved the problem for me in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for about 2 hours, and your solution has worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

`Ð’Ñ–Ð·Ð¾Ñ‡ÐºÐ¸` is [*Mojibake*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for `Візочки`.  It happens when you don't have utf8/utf8mb4 everywhere.  In particular, node.js needs something like

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... , charset : 'utf8mb4'});
```